# pulling shipping information from android PayPal sdk

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment-processing

Does the new native PayPal sdk for android have the ability to pull shipping information to give to the merchant? The sample code provided on the PayPal site will process cards etc, but it appears to me that the api only provides payment confirmation. What good is this api if you don't know where to send your product?

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am also stuck here...did u got any information on it?

Comment: @Nishant Looks to me like it doesn't provide this. I had to create a series of checkout dialogues and then upload the information to the google app engine to store it so I could pull the shipping info later on. Hopefully they add this to the api soon.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff from PayPal at your service.  The PayPal Android SDK does not support shipping addresses just yet.  Your feedback is heard, and we plan to add the feature as soon we can!

Comment: i also want to get the shipping address in my app stored in my PayPal account from mSDK while making purchase/transaction.