# Could Paypal Android SDK ask for shipping address?

Tags: android, paypal

I am using [Paypal-Android-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) for purchasing items from my app. But SDK does not prompt me for shipping address. I found Jeff's response for [pulling shipping information from android PayPal sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221590/pulling-shipping-information-from-android-paypal-sdk) post as

The PayPal Android SDK does not support shipping addresses just yet. Your feedback is heard, and we plan to add the feature as soon we can!

Just wanted to know, if any updates on shipping address in SDK? If not, how the shipping will be managed by PayPal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff here again.  Sorry, no updates yet.  You'll have to manage shipping addresses prior to sending the payment to PayPal.  Don't worry though, this feature will be released in the near future!

Comment: Thanks! But still confused, how could I send shipping address to PayPal? Is there any provision by which I can send address to my server & server could forward it to PayPal?